# Can I show search result from a website to my own app?

Tags: javascript, android, html, ionic-framework

I'm sorry before, I'm New in Applications Development. I want to ask how to show search result from a website to my app?

For example when I input some data [like this](https://6aaa8359-a-62cb3a1a-s-sites.googlegroups.com/site/donytri86/Screenshot_1.jpg?attachauth=ANoY7coAde580Wat5ou6E4_LGGw_0lsu6rHjBNyjUn3LkWHUszYZjnNSYj7JuuyM-GFytaP6P06mCMB23BjuXjVLbzvr8soINZvm3RO-F4hPILxN6bV7_MWQO147H3B2uR3iparApDq9xGd2hKoXFaXjinKxpalwbQc5tbEMbuLC0Or0F9RH574yMcSmmunTnA8YYUVtLoEgEz7VCGMUDGmSh52dGsMvsg%3D%3D&attredirects=1) and hit the button, how can i show the search result from [this website](http://nisn.data.kemdikbud.go.id/page/data)?

*how to use the http method in html app to submit some data from applications to the web and displays the results to the application

Answer (score 1):

You need to find out what the website is doing, and then replicate that in your application. In the website you've provided, when you enter a code and click the button, an HTTP `POST` request is sent to this address

```
http://nisn.data.kemdikbud.go.id/page/data
```

You will need to copy and change all of the data in the request, and perform that same request from your application, in theory.

**Difficulties**

- The site provided is using ASP.Net Webforms and there are lots of fields as well as viewstate being sent back in the request. So it may be quite difficult if not impossible to replicate this functionality.
- If there are fields that contain data known only by the server such as session state, authentication tokens etc, this will be very difficult or impossible for the most part
- The format of the response is a whole bunch of HTML, which is basically re-rendering the large majority of the page. In order to extract the data you want, you need t inspect the format of the HTML and write code accordingly using an HTML parser to retrieves the values you're after. This is very brittle, because as soon as they change their HTML slightly, your code breaks and your app stops working.
- This may not be legal, have you checked whether you are allowed to use the data from that site in a third party application?
- They appear to be using the Telerik control library. I am not familiar with it, but it may compound the difficulty of the task in the same way that session state and authentication tokens will.
- They may not allow requests from across domains, this can easily be faked by changing the `Origin` and possibly `Referrer` headings in the request.

**Getting it done**

In order to do this, I first suggest you look at the legality of it. Maybe you can ask the company if they have an API or service that provides such data, it will make it exponentially easier if they do. If you want to proceed on you need to start inspecting the requests. Go to the site in your web browser and check out the network XHR requests being made when you enter a code and click the button. Here's an example from that site:

[image]